# RxJava with Firebase Remove child events

Tags: firebase, rx-java

I'm using firebase to store my data and it is structured this way:

```
users {
   userid {information here}
}
friends {
   userid {
      friendid1:true
      friendid2:true
   }
}
```

If a friendid is added or removed, then an appropriate event should be called.
If the user information is changed, then an event update should be triggered.

So far I have:

```
RxFirebaseDatabase.observeFriendList(/*Path to friends id list*/)
                .flatMap(new Func1<RxFirebaseChildEvent, Observable<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<User> call(RxFirebaseChildEvent stringBooleanPair) {
                        //This is a childeventlistener callback
                        //The key of RxFirebaseChildEvent is the friendid
                        switch (stringBooleanPair.getEventType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                return RxFirebaseDatabase.observeUserInformation(/*path to user list*/.child(stringBooleanPair.getKey()), User.class);
                            case REMOVED:
                                return null; //What do I do here to unregister the listener?
                        }
                    }
                }).subscribe(user -> {
                    //This is a ValueEventListener callback that returns the user
                    //Add, remove or update here, how?
        });
```

How do I remove the specific user listener when a friendId is removed and also call add/remove/update on that user to update the view?

Comment: You don't need to do that `RxFirebase` library already remove your listener when you `unSubscribe` your `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a somewhat hacked-together version, would love to see a better implementation though.

```
//refUsers is path to users

List<String> userKeys = new ArrayList<>();
RxFirebaseDatabase.observeFriendList(/*Path to friends id list*/)
                .flatMap(new Func1<RxFirebaseChildEvent, Observable<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<User> call(RxFirebaseChildEvent stringBooleanPair) {
                        //This is a childeventlistener callback
                        //The key of RxFirebaseChildEvent is the friendid
                        switch (stringBooleanPair.getEventType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                userKeys.add(stringBooleanPair.getKey());//User Key
                                return RxFirebaseDatabase
                                       .observeUserInformation(refUsers.child(stringBooleanPair.getKey()),
                                                               User.class,
                                                               Eventype.ADDED)
                                       .takeWhile((user) -> userKeys.contains(user.getKey()));
                            case REMOVED:
                                userKeys.remove(userid);
                                return RxFirebaseDatabase
                                        .observeUserInformation(refUsers.child(userid),
                                                                User.class,
                                                                Const.EventType.REMOVED)
                                        .take(1);
                        }
                    }
                }).subscribe(userEvent -> {
                   //Returns an object that contains the user and the eventype (added, updated or removed)
        });
```

Basically, I'm keeping track of the users that are in the friends list and only returning an event if the userid is still watched.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that RxFirebase library already remove your listener when you unsubscribe your Observable, you can see it if you check the implementation:

```
subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
  @Override
  public void call() {
    query.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
}
```

I suggest you to check as reference(or just use it) my RxJava2 library if you want to update your app from RxJava to RxJava2:

https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase

If you are interested of it, you can see the differences between both RxJava  [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0).